# magit-define-popup-switch not enabled by default

Tags: magit

I'm trying to teach magit that `git pull --rebase` should always `--autostash`.  `pull --rebase` is always my default, so I want `--autostash` to be the default as well.

The 5th argument of `magit-define-popup-switch` is [documented](https://magit.vc/manual/magit-popup/Customizing-existing-popups.html) as

```
If optional ENABLE is non-nil, then the switch is on by default.
```

however, when I do

```
(magit-define-popup-switch 'magit-pull-popup ?A "Autostash" "--autostash" t)
```

the switch is not *on* by default.  I get the same behavior when I simply do

```
(magit-define-popup-switch 'magit-pull-popup ?A "Autostash" "--autostash")
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That argument only adds the argument to the default value of the respective variable, but you are probably not using the default value.

If you save a popup's arguments using <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> (from the popup), then that value will be used. You have probably done that in the past and can easily "fix" it by doing it again, this time after enabling `--autostash`. Alternatively you can use the Custom interface to reset `magit-push-arguments` to the default value.

Comment: Indeed `magit-pull-arguments` was defined to `--rebase`, probably from a quite old magit version; clearing this did the trick.   In my mind I was adding a new switch, so this switch could not have a previous state, and should have honored the default setting I specified.  Now I understand that switch don't have states, but popups do have sets of enabled switches and defaults for such sets.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that last sentence summarizes it well.